# Updating selected row to database with button click

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to update selected row in datagrid when i click on button `Ponuda`.

[image]

The problem is, when i click on button, nothing happens, but when i restart application, whole list is updated. So i need a way to update only the row i have selected and to update it right away and not after application restart.

This is my code for button click :

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           // count = 120;
           // tmr.Start();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source=ZC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=Aukcija;integrated security=true;"))
            {
                    DataTable cena1 = new DataTable();
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(" UPDATE Predmet SET trenutnaCena = trenutnaCena + 1", conn);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Predmet SET trenutnaCena = trenutnaCena + 1", conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DA.Update(cena1);
                    conn.Close();

            }

        }
```

Comment: You're never changing the data in the dataGrid so it won't update on its own, you'll need to repopulate it

Comment: I tried to add `aukcija_bazeDataGrid.DataContext = aukcijeTable;` after `Da.Update(cena1);` but still the same. `aukcija_bazeDataGrid` is the name of my `DataGrid`.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to unbind and rebind the data source every time you update it

Comment: You are creating new `DataTable` each time you do an update. Try setting `cena1` as the DataContext for your `DataGrid`.

Comment: Now whole `DataTable` disappeared, although it still updated after restarting application...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bindings, it SHOULD be updating. The reason it might not be is if whatever object your binding to the DataGrid (which should be an ObservableCollection or class based on one) does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, the collection will never know a property change occurred.

If you haven't already, implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise OnPropertyChanged event for each property. Then, when a value changes, it'll reflect both in the DataGrid and the actual collection being bound.

You'll want to make sure you have an event that updates the database with the new collection values whenever such and such happens (which I noticed `button3_Click` takes care of).

If this doesn't work, let me know, because it should.

Comment: Sorry for a really late response, can you give me an example of PropertyChanged event for my code, since i am not very familiar with it?